# Change ChartImg.axd path

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms, microsoft-chart-controls, asp.net-charts

I have an `.ascx` file embedded in my MVC app using [this extension](http://malvinly.com/2011/02/28/using-web-forms-user-controls-in-an-asp-net-mvc-project/). In the `ascx` there is a `asp:Chart` object.

When I open my page `http://localhost:56854/Machines/Details/1` there is no chart image. Looking at page source I've found that there is problem with path to ChartImg.axd. The image got

```
src="/Machines/Details/ChartImg.axd?i=chart_8b0e12daec9447feb9986442e53243d2_0.png&g=becaa2f59bec483eab9e9103620711eb"
```

Accesing just

```
localhost:56854/ChartImg.axd?i=chart_8b0e12daec9447feb9986442e53243d2_0.png&g=becaa2f59bec483eab9e9103620711eb
```

in web browser gave me correct image. My question is: how to change this path?

Comment: post some more code..

Comment: i don't know which part would be helpful. could you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution. Just add these line to the `RouteConfig.cs` file:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");        
routes.IgnoreRoute("{controller}/{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("{controller}/{action}/{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

Comment: do you know why this fixed it?

Comment: this has more information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631526/asp-net-charting-control-no-longer-working-with-net-4

Comment: @Simon_Weaver thanks for info, the solution with the routes worked for me but i don't know what was wrong, i don't have access to that project anymore so i can't try other solutions, thank you anyway!

Comment: Thx for the reply. I found another link which I posted after this comment below.